# indexing impact

Tags: postgresql, index, python

If I have a table with 4 columns(a,b,c,d)

I create the following index for this table :

```
CREATE INDEX index_t
ON table(a,b,c);
```

Will the PostgreSQL optimizer consider using the index in the following case:

```
WHERE a = v1 and b = v2 and c = v3 and d=f4;
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) and you will know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PostgreSQL will definitely consider the index.

It may still choose not to use the index, for example if the table is too small or the condition is not selective enough.

You can temporarily

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

to see if PostgreSQL can use the index or not. Just `EXPLAIN` the query.